# django mysql force usage of index

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm using django orm and mysql.
From some reason mysql is using the wrong index.
I want to manually override the index used.
I saw that the django team decided from cross platform reason to prevent usage of with_hints extension that would force an index.
Does anyone have any kind if solution \ proposal how I could get mysql to use the correct index then through django?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django supports raw sql queries to fit your needs, see the documentation article [Performing raw SQL queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/).

> When the model query APIs don’t go far enough, you can fall back to writing raw SQL. Django gives you two ways of performing raw SQL queries: you can use Manager.raw() to perform raw queries and return model instances, or you can avoid the model layer entirely and execute custom SQL directly.

Comment: I'm using tastypie so I'm not sure how go about editing the mysql query directly. Do you know by any chance?

Comment: No, sorry. Never used tastypie.

Answer (score 3):

The [django-mysql](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-mysql) extension supports indexing hints.  See [the docs](http://django-mysql.readthedocs.org/en/latest/queryset_extensions.html?highlight=index#django_mysql.models.use_index) for details.

Comment: If you recommend a library, please show how it can be applied.

Comment: I used `force_index`