# Use index in django

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

How would I run the following statement in the django ORM, or would I need to do `.raw()` ?

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM messages USE INDEX (created_at);
```

Without the `USE INDEX`:

```
Messages.objects.all().count()
```

Comment: MySql should use the appropriate index for such a simple query... are you sure you need this?  Can you post the `EXPLAIN` plan for the query w/o the `USE INDEX`?

Comment: Yes, mysql is using an index that contains a lot of null values. It improves performance by 6x when I force an index on the PK of the table.

Comment: Doesn't look like you can do it without manually specifying it through raw - https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11003.

Comment: Does the 6x persist if you run it twice?  I'm suspecting that the 6x was loading the "bad" index into cache, and it will run much faster the next time.

Comment: Available in the django-mysql extension, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25353945/django-mysql-force-usage-of-index/32917099#32917099